# Duplicate title and description due to query string [ ? ] how to resolve it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

These pages causing duplicate content ..........

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=1568`
and so on 1568, 4420 , .......

I don't know how to get rid of it

I want to redirect these kind of all links redirect to my main forum thread

/forum/showthread-1-1.htm

Please tell me how to write .htaccess code to have no negative effect of these links

these links not present on my site right now but google webmaster tool rapidly saying this is is duplicate content

please tell me how to redirect 301

like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[I copied this code from stack overflow]

Comment: You question is unclear. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I AM FACING DUPLICATE CONTENT PROBLEM
SOME OF MY WEBSITES LINKS HAVING DUPLICATE META DISCRIPTION AND TITLE TAG SO THAT I WANT TO REDIRECT THOSE LINK TO MAIN FORUM LINK

MY WEBSITE IS SATTAMATKA.ORG AND LINKS HAVING SAME D AND T ARE FOLLOWS...

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=1568
  
/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=1803 

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=1936

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=1962

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=1967

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=2205

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=2290

/forum/index.php?forumID=1&ID=1&start=4049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+forum/(index\.php)?\?forumID=1&ID=\d+&start=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/showthread-1-1.htm? [R=302,L]
```

**PS:** Place above as **first rule** in `/forum/.htaccess` file if that already exists.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR FOR ANSWER ............
CAN I USE 301 IN ABOVE CODE FOR PERMANENT REDIRECTION

Comment: Yes once you verify it is working you can change `302` to `301`. Also you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.